# Spring Boot + JPA + mysql ... wrong approach?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I have an general question here since I am really frustrated and unsure right now.

I have:

- Working PHP REST API
- Ugly MySQL DB

And want to refactor it into:

- Spring boot Microservice(s)
- with JPA / Hibernate
- MySQL DB

I have a Spring boot service running on local fabric8 cluster.

Now I want to access the MySQL DB.

- Created the **POJOs** / Entities with **Dali Eclipse** (Hibernate or JPA 2.1 tried both)
- Tried simple **CRUDRepository.findAll()**

And here the problems started (well there were many before but ok)

1. I had a naming convention issue with generated POJOs and DB
   *solved by config:*

   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
2. Several JDBC driver and Class version Problems in Eclipse which had to be *fixed by hand with downloaded jars.*
3. Infinite Loop with crudRepo.findAll() cause recursing POJO relationships
   *solved by*:

   Setting a `@JsonManagedReference` under EACH `@OneToMany`
   and a `@JsonBackReference`under EACH `@ManyToOne`

I know things will get more complicated because I have DB requests which needs **only some values from a table** and other hand some requests which are based on **several tables (joins)** 
And I have problems **finding the right docs** which describe such use cases.
Or do just need to create an own POJO for each UseCase??

Now my question is:

- Do I have the right approach or is there a better suggestion?
- What documentation did I miss which could explain such problems?

Since things tend never to work as intended since I started this project I struggle if I do right. 
Especially the MySQL **DB access** seems so problematic with **Hibernate/Spring-boot**.

I worked with JPA earlier and find it very comfortable, but It seems so unneccessary complicated now.

I would appreciate if you could share your mind on that!

Comment: JsonBackReference is a jackson annotation, so if it is solving recursion problems, they aren't related to JPA or spring-boot.  You are using multiple technologies to do very different things JSON<->Java<->DB and have to have your model, the config and jars appropriate for each leg.  You haven't presented a question we can help with as we don't know what approach you are taking, and it is opinion based anyway.  there are numerous JPA demos and tutorials you can look at and adapt to your needs.

Comment: Maybe thats exactly what I need to hear (read). There are so many parts working together so I loosing the overview what symptoms are caused by what... I ll take some time for getting a better overview before I continue.
Thanks for that little headbutt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course Spring (Boot) is huge and at the beginning it can be overwhelming - especially if you add web and persistence layers - but if you know where to start it becomes really easy to realize nearly any requirement.

What exactly do you mean with "generated POJOs"? Usually you write your Java Entities manually and define the mapping to the (already existing) database schema with annotations (or XML), e.g. a simple Hibernate mapping could look like [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-annotations-entity). So if you do it this way there should be no naming issues anymore.

The solution "fixed by hand with downloaded jars" sounds strange, better use a dependency management tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/). E.g. with maven you can also [include / exclude](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) certain dependencies if something does not fit your needs. Spring does support maven and gradle out of the box.

A lot of JSON / Jackson tutorials can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson), the [baeldung site](http://www.baeldung.com/) is in general a good point to look for spring tutorials.

To manage things like "only some values from a table" or "several tables (joins)", [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) and especially [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) are useful, but beware of the problems with generated queries. A good source of knowledge about mappings and persistence stuff in general is [Vlad's Blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/). If you want to work without Spring Data JPA, there are also [Hibernate result set mappings](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/).

Comment: "Generated POJOs" created automaticly by the Dali tool in eclipse. But with all relations in it too.

Comment: Ah, ok. I do not know that tool. But writing the Entities manually is more reliable, imho.

Answer (score 1):

1. As said earlier you can skip following the naming convention part if you map the column names correctly using either way of annotation or xml.
2. I would suggest if you start using hibernate with hql and named queries. If there have been stored procedures originally, use named queries again.
3. Spring boot can be very handy if you are going micro services way but you need to implement a binding tool like maven before that. Just changing the latest version number in pom.xml will let the latest jar be on the classpath automatically(downloaded). Initially the process may seem elusive and time taking but it will help your team with a lot of flexibilities in future.

Comment: Thanks, that hits some important points for. I ll keep that in mind.

Comment: @GregorSklorz you're welcome. Consider using maven first, a testing tool for microservices and health or registry keeper for all microservices.

Comment: @GregorSklorz please send a upvote if you liked the answer.